# For loop performs weird increment jumps

Tags: c++

I have the following code, which is part of a larger program. Here N = 108 and NDIM = 3.

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
  for(j=0; j<NDIM; j++){
    r[i][j] = rn[i][j];
    printf("The new element (%d, %d) is %lf\n", i,j, r[i][j]);
    boxsize[i] = boxsizen[i];
  }
}
```

Compiling and running the program gives a segmentation fault, which I have traced to the line

```
r[i][j] = rn[i][j];
```

The double for loop seems to behave fine until we get to the point where i should take the value 46, instead i jumps from 45 to 1074846117, which is obviously a problem. What could cause this problem?

EDIT:

r and rn are defined as follows

```
double r[N][NDIM];
double rn[N][NDIM];
```

and boxsize/boxsizen are given by

```
double boxsize[NDIM];
double boxsizen[NDIM];
```

I have replaced the code for r and rn by

```
double **r;
r = malloc((N+2)*sizeof(double *));
for(i = 0; i<N; i++){
    r[i] = malloc(NDIM * sizeof(double));
    }

double **rn;
rn = malloc((N+2)*sizeof(double *));
for(i = 0; i<N; i++){
    rn[i] = malloc(NDIM * sizeof(double));
    }
```

and the code seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Why the downvote? Should I add more information or show more work?

Comment: The downvote is presumably because you've only posted a small code snippet rather than a complete example.

Comment: You should post your definitions for `r` and `rn`.

Comment: Ah, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)'s the link for advice on posting questions like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a textbook buffer overrun. The typical cause is you didn't allocate enough space for your arrays -- `r` or `boxsize` is probably the culprit -- although there could be memory corruption or other problems elsewhere. A typical debugging approach from here is to very carefully check all of your indexing and all of your allocations to find the mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

`boxsize` and `boxsizen` have dimension `NDIM` which is `3`, however you index them with `i` which runs from `0` up to `N-1` which is `107`. This is a buffer overflow.

If you adjusted `r` and `rn` but did not fix this bug then your code is still bugged. Perhaps it just happens to be overwriting memory that is not doing anything important, instead of trashing other stack variables.